# RequestDispatcher with Struts2

Tags: struts2

Currently I fail to `getRequestDispatcher` from Struts2 as below:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = httpReq.getRequestDispatcher("/category.htm");
```

Error was show as below:

```
The requested resource (/xxxx/category.htm) is not available.
```

but it working well when `http:/xxxx/yyyy/category.htm?id=21` execute
does anyone have idea?

Answer (score 1):

If it works with the `/category.htm` URL hitting `?id=21`, but that goes to `/xxx/yyy/category.htm`, then you're not making the same request as the final URL in your `getRequestDispatcher()` invocation. Try this instead:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = httpReq.getRequestDispatcher("/yyy/category.htm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolve with post below, anyway, thanks John for your reply :)

http://old.nabble.com/Block-accessing-in-some-path-with-filter.-td23631279.html

What I did is just added these into filter-mapping element for struts filter in web.xml:

```
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
```